# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : com/google/gson/JsonElement on playframework does not work when starting the server

Tags: playframework-2.5

in sbt.build add to libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.gson" % "gson" % "2.2.4" but when doing deploy in intellij with the command: 'activator clean stage' and raise the server, the following error appears:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbU4w.png)

Comment: Sorry, is  build.sbt

Comment: Edit your question

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, here the solution:

In file  generate of play in bin folder, validate the variable APP_CLASSPATH contain all libs routes, so was missing on my installation the file .bat updated. In my case I had only installed the lib and conf folder of my deploy.

Thanks